# How can I extract a .zip file with 7zip with a cmd command?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, zip, 7-zip

I have the following problem:

I have a **test.zip**

This test .zip should be extracted to a **"test"** folder.

But i have a test1, test2..., test23. So no matter how its named, the folder should always have be **testXX**

I have the following code:

```
C:\7za.exe x C:\test* -oC:\Archiv
```

How can I create a unzipped folder which is named like the zipfile?

Comment: Are you looking for executing a script on one zip file, or for looping over all of them? Do you really keep files in the root `C:\`?

Comment: no i don't keep then in C: its just for showing purpose. I always get a generated file, which is a .zip file. Now i always have to open it manually and move a file in it and then zip it again. Its just for fun purpose to skip those steps (extracting and moving manually).

Comment: The files have full folder path in the zip, then I would have expected it to work.  Yu can alsways write a script to create a folder name to match the zip name.

Comment: Check out `-o*` https://stackoverflow.com/a/57907078/7411885. Something like `7z.exe e "C:\test*.zip" -o*` should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

An untested idea for a script that accepts a `testxx` parameter
and unzips it :

```
mkdir C:\Archiv\%1
C:\7za.exe x "%1" -oC:\Archiv\%1
```

Some modification is required if the folder or file-names can include
blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I did it like this:

```
C:\7za.exe x C:\test* -oC:\folder\*
```